# Not showing alert even when I add Camera Usage Description / Photo Library Usage Description

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I have camera/ photo library in my app, so I add request permission in plist. However, after running app, it does not even pop up alert. Just access to pick photo / camera. Is there anything I miss to add?

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you didn't already grant the access?  Try deleting the app and build and run again.  Check in settings what app access to.

Comment: @MwcsMac I am sure this is first running app cuz I tried many times. Setting also show that I allow notification.

Comment: `UIImagePickerController` doesn't require any permissions on iOS 11+

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Requesting Authorization for Media Capture on iOS:
   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/requesting_authorization_for_media_capture_on_ios

Configure Your App's Info.plist File:

If your app uses device cameras, include the 'NSCameraUsageDescription' key in your app’s Info.plist file.

Verify and Request Authorization for Capture:

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
         switch AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video) {
          case .authorized:  // The user has previously granted access to the camera.
              .....

          case .notDetermined: // The user has not yet been asked for camera access.
               AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { granted in
                if granted {
                    .....
                }
        }

         case .denied: // The user has previously denied access.
             return
         case .restricted: // The user can't grant access due to restrictions.
           return
       }
 }
```

Comment: I add this in my code, it shows successfully, but after I deleted app and run again, it does not show again.